# Associative Array, HTML: Misaligned table

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am getting misaligned table and need your inputs in fixing that. 
I have an associative array that looks like below and need to push the values in an HTML table. The associative array would be of fixed size always.

```
array ( 'Objective' => array ( 0 => 'Page Likes', ), 'Gender' => array ( 0 => 'Male 13-17 (5.4% cheaper)Male 25-34 (0.81% cheaper)', ), 'Placement' => array ( 0 => 'Mobile Feed Other (1.2% cheaper)', ), )
```

I'm using the below function that takes two arguments as associative arrays. One array is used for heading and other arrays have the values that needs to be pushed into the row.

```
function generateTable3($associative_array,$associative_array1){
echo '<table width="680" class="optimization_table" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><thead><tr><th style="text-align:center" colspan=1>';
echo implode('</th><th style="text-align:center"  colspan=2>',$associative_array);
echo '</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
var_export($associative_array1);
$rowCount = count( current( $associative_array1 ) );
 for ($x=0; $x<$rowCount; $x++) {
    echo "<tr>";

   //this section needs your help
    foreach ($associative_array1 as $key => $data){
        echo "<td>".trim($data[ $x ])."</td>";
       // echo trim($data[ $x ]);
       // echo "<br>";

    }

    echo "</tr>\n";
}



echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

current output looks like below:
[image]

expected output:
[image]

can someone pls help in fixing this.

Comment: You are missing `colspan` on your second `td`.

Comment: possible to provide a line of code pls

Comment: You can also remove `colspan=2` from your `th` as answered by **Richard**

Comment: I added the `colspan=2` but then the table is not uniform. The column heading is not aligned with the column of values

Comment: thanks, it worked !! Please post this as answer and I shall accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the third line you have `colspan=2`; this makes your headers span 2 columns. Remove that and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo implode('</th><th style="text-align:center"  colspan=2>',$associative_array);
```

Remove colspan from the above code

```
echo implode('</th><th style="text-align:center">',$associative_array);
```